# How to identify associated widget when list item is clicked?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview, android-contacts

I have been able to create a ListActivity that displays a header and a footer, and sandwiched between these a custom layout that contains on each row three checkboxes and a Contact name (reading from the Contacts database). I use a SimpleCursorAdapter to display this info. My problem has been getting the OnListItemClicked()* to fire. I click in the ListView (on the checkboxes AND on the name of the Contact) and my breakpoint is never reached. So: What must I do to get that to fire. I AM setting it, like so:

```
lv.SetOnListItemClicked(etc);
```

- I think it is; I'm not at my dev machine right now

But even if I am able to get the click event to fire, how will I be able to identify the associated checkboxes? They are named ckbx1, ckbx2, and ckbx3 (or so) in the layout file, but there will be (Contacts.Count) of them, so how can I positively identify which ones have been clicked?

My other option is to dynamically create the widgets in the Activity's OnCreate().

My pseudocode for this is the following, and I'm open to suggestions/feedback on whether this makes or is [not] the best way to go about it:

```
OnCreate() {
  Cursor c = getContacts();
  for (i = 0, i == c.Count, i++) {
    int id = getContactID(i);
    CheckBox ckbx1 = new CheckBox();
    ckbx1.Tag = id;
    ckbx1.OnClick = Checkbox1Click();

    CheckBox ckbx2 = new CheckBox();
    ckbx2.Tag = id;
    ckbx2.OnClick = Checkbox2Click();

    CheckBox ckbx3 = new CheckBox();
    ckbx3.Tag = id;
    ckbx3.OnClick = Checkbox3Click();

    TextView tv = new TextView();
    tv.Text = getContactName(i);
}

Checkbox1Click() {
  int ContactID = (CheckBox)object.Tag;
  switch (ContactID)
  case 1:
    WriteToDB(1, Option1);
  case 2:
    WriteToDB(2, Option1);
  ...
}
```

This (especially the CheckboxClick event handler) is obviously very rough, but I think you can get the drift of where I'm going with this - saving the "checked" state of the Checkboxes to a SQLite DB so that I know Contact1 wants email (or twitter feed, or whatever the other two checkboxes indicate).

So is my previous method salvageable, or should I go down this new path (or veer off a little from that?)

Answer (score 1):

Usually i uses [`View.setTag`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) to identify a view instance. For example,

```
checkBox.setTag("listItem1");
```